# How to safely remove boost::shared_memory_object

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I am using a boost::shared_memory_object for IPC. I have a client and server. I use two message queues. One for sending requests to the server and one for receiving replies from the server. It is an asynchronous protocol. My problem is that I do not know how to safely remove the shared_memory_objects in case of failures. Consider this scenario:

1. Server starts
2. Client starts and connects to server; message queues are created in shared memory.
3. Client sends regular heartbeats to server; everything is ok.
4. Client gets held up with too much processing; misses some heartbeats
5. Server thinks client is dead, cleans up the queues (shared_memory_object::remove will remove the queue even if there is a running process with a handle to that shared memory segment open)
6. Client finishes processing; tries to write to message queue that has been deleted:

All hell breaks loose here. Sometimes the write succeeds, sometimes it crashes. Who knows whether other process, after the message queue has been deleted, have created new shared memory objects on the same memory address...

Clearly, if the client thinks that the server is down and it deletes the queue, then the server thread that tries to read/write to the queue might crash (or corrupt memory).

Comment: Since you're trying to clean up system resources in the event of a client dying on you, I think you'd need to forcibly kill the client if you really think it's dead.  Otherwise you'll leave zombie processes lying around.  Having your server kill clients might not be a good option, so you might need a third "watchdog" process to do this for you.  But the gist of it is, if you really think the client is dead, kill it first, then delete the message queue.

Comment: doing the heartbeat in a separate thread ?